# How to connect ccxt to java or kotlin, Or recommend a ccxt kind of library for java or kotlin

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading, cryptocurrency, binance-api-client, ccxt

I need to connect to different crypto exchanges from java or kotlin, but most of the libraries I have found are for python or other languages, I would like to know how to connect ccxt to java or kotlin, or to know if there is an alternative library for my needs.

I expected to find a guide on how to use ccxt with java or kotlin but I could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

there is actually no active Java project to connect to crypto exchanges. There is https://github.com/knowm/XChange but it's not supported as much as CCXT, which is updated almost on a daily basis with a very responsive community.

The best way is actually to run CCXT in a small application and find a way for your java application to communicate with it (through a middleware). It's a bit overkill but it works.